# How to use StreamWriter in recursive methods?

Tags: c#

My problem is i am trying to write a vector recursion algorithm output to a file, using StreamWriter.

The code, shown below, prints the expected output in the console, but when i try to print it in the StreamWriter, i get only X times 1 (ex. 1111, 111111, 11).

Here is the coode:

```
static void VectorRecursion(int[] vectors, int index)
    {
        if (index == vectors.Length)
        {
            //This works, prints the expected output.
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", vectors));

            //This part doesn't work.
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(String.Join("", vectors));
                writer.Close();
            }

            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            vectors[index] = i;
            VectorRecursion(vectors, index + 1);
        }
    }
```

Hel will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ? Do you have an error ? What is the message then ?

Comment: There is no error, it just prints only 1s. For example, if input is 2, you should get result 00, then 01, then 10 and then 11. This output is printed in the console, but not in the writer. In the writer, the output is only 11.

Comment: Could it be because when you instantiate a new StreamWriter with a specific file name, it overrides the previous file and it's content ? Could you try instantiating the StreamWriter a single time outside of your function and passing it as parameter to your recursive function ?

Comment: Either configure the writer to append to the file or better pass the writer to your function and initialize/close it once.

Comment: Declare the SreamWriter as static ouside the method in global space.  Then change to : using (writer = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))

Comment: Why don't you split your persistence logic from your data population logic?

Comment: Like people explained new writer erase/over write the file with the same name. here is a simple poc. https://dotnetfiddle.net/58bhbM